# How do I fix "Cannot find name CSSTranslate"? VSCode vs tsc

Tags: typescript

I've got a program that works when I run it in a development environment, and looks great in VSCode, but **tsc is complaining** about various unknown names and properties.  This is strange because **VSCode has no problem** with my file.

Can anyone tell me what's going on or how to fix this?

Here are the error messages:
[image: Error Messages]

As you can see here, my editor knows about CSS.px(),
[image: Tooltip shows syntax for CSS.px()]

And CSSTransformValue.
[image]

The results are similar when I look at CSSTranslate and attributeStyleMap when applied to an SVGGElement.

Here is the complete source code: https://github.com/TradeIdeasPhilip/classic-chuzzle/tree/55df4a64623755c238ff97fadac0c8205982a8b7

I'd appreciate any insights into what's going on or how to fix it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  I needed to update to the latest version of TypeScript.

Part of the confusion was that there's a **local** installation of TypeScript and a **global** installation!  Also, there's a way to update `typescript` which is different from updating `tsc`.

In the end I typed `npm update typescript` (without `-g`!) and that fixed my problem.  That caused me to update some other packages, to keep npm happy.

The fix can be found here:  https://github.com/TradeIdeasPhilip/classic-chuzzle/commit/526dab1b7a92dc547c68af1c773f625c3723b9e6#diff-053150b640a7ce75eff69d1a22cae7f0f94ad64ce9a855db544dda0929316519